# NoClassDefFoundError at runtime with ant

Tags: java, ant, configuration, noclassdeffounderror, build.xml

well I'm trying to configure the project with Ant and this is what I get:

```
     D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS\src\lib>dir
     Volume in drive D is WinMedia
     Volume Serial Number is 8ED9-B662
    
     Directory of D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS\src\lib
    
    2012.11.20  16:11    <DIR>          .
    2012.11.20  16:11    <DIR>          ..
    2012.10.16  22:03           315.805 commons-lang3-3.1.jar
    2012.10.23  23:08           176.897 commons-validator-1.4.0.jar
    2012.11.20  15:30    <DIR>          hibernate
    2012.11.16  04:48           253.160 junit-4.10.jar
    2012.10.22  02:02           489.883 log4j-1.2.17.jar
    2012.10.31  23:00         1.581.066 mockito-all-1.9.5.jar
    2012.11.02  19:54           651.643 mybatis-3.1.1.jar
    2012.11.01  04:37           832.960 mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
                   7 File(s)      4.301.414 bytes
                   3 Dir(s)   7.277.907.968 bytes free
    
    D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS\src\lib>cd ../..
    
    D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS>
    D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS>
    D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS>ant run
    Buildfile: D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS\build.xml
    
    init:
    
    compile:
        [javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS\build
    
    jar:
          [jar] Building jar: D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS\dist
    \jar\PIRS.jar
    
    run:
         [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apach
    e/log4j/Logger
         [java]     at com.nortal.pirs.userinterface.fakestarter.FakeUserInterface.<
    init>(Unknown Source)
         [java]     at com.nortal.pirs.userinterface.fakestarter.FakeUserInterface.m
    ain(Unknown Source)
         [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    
         [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
         [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
         [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
         [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
         [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
         [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    
         [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
         [java]     ... 2 more
         [java] Java Result: 1
    
    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
    Total time: 2 seconds

D:\Dropbox\EclipseWorkspace\PIRS>
```

Well first you can see I have the log4j in the folder src/lib and in the second part you can see that it's not found at runtime. Pretty strange, because it compiles fine, it just seems to not be able to find that at runtime.

My build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="PIRS" default="dist" basedir=".">
    <description>PIRS</description>
    <property name="src" location="src"/>
    <property name="build" location="build"/>
    <property name="dist" location="dist"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" location="src/lib"/>
    
    <path id="classpath">        
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>
    
    <target name="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
    </target>
    
    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
        </classpath>
        </javac>
    </target>
    
    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="generate the jar">
        <mkdir dir="${dist}/jar"/>
        <jar destfile="${dist}/jar/PIRS.jar" basedir="${build}">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.nortal.pirs.userinterface.fakestarter.FakeUserInterface"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
   </target>
   
    <target name="clean" description="clean up" >
        <delete dir="${build}"/>
        <delete dir="${dist}"/>
    </target>
    
    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java jar="${dist}/jar/PIRS.jar" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="classpath"/>
            
        </java>
    </target>
        
</project>
```

Actually the line  doesn't seem to change anything.

Well, any ideas on it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: classpath as property may be getting set once and not taking your assignments.  Try running ant with -debug, which will write information on property , class path etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You met a common issue here: **when you run something with the `java -jar ...` command, the `-classpath ...` property is dropped.** The reason is security (Jar files can be digitally signed to ensure they weren't modified and it would be so easy to make `java` load a different dependency Jar file with the same content but with hijacked functionality).

The solution is simple: include the `Class-Path: ...` attribute too in your `MANIFEST.MF` file as you did with `Main-Class: ...`.